# Source on approximant fortition

Tags: phonetics, reference-request, sociophonetics

I'm starting a project that examines the phonetics of palatal approximant fortition (with a variety of outcomes) in several dialects of Spanish.

There's a great deal of existing Spanish linguistics literature on this, but I'd like to branch out and see what's going on cross-linguistically, too.

Does anyone have any recommendations of phonologists/phoneticians doing work like this and/or possible references?

Answer (score 1):

The feature theory of palatalization in [The Sound Pattern of English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sound_Pattern_of_English) is meant to cover historical developments in Slavic.  Another reference that occurs to me is a paper by Bhat on palatalization from a Stanford project on universals of language.

My own observation is that the articulations of English syllable onset and syllable offset jod are quite different, the first being a palato-alveolar rather than a palatal.  As in "yam" vs. "pay".

Answer (score 1):

**Vulgar Latin to modern Romance**

This is very likely well known to you. The emergence of the phoneme /ʒ/ written "j", from /j/.

Classical Latin *ego* /ˈe.ɡo/, probably elided the middle /g/ to form Vulgar Latin **eo*, which must have been pronouced something like /jo/, yielding modern Sardinian *eo* /ˈɛo/, Spanish *yo* /jo/, Italian *io* /ˈi.o/, but Central Catalan and some instances of Old French *jo* /ʒɔ/, modern French *je* /ʒə/.

The effect is much stronger with the /j/ at the beginning of Latin words. See for example [*iocus*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/iocus#Latin), which underwent fortition in most varieties of Romance.

**Middle Chinese loans in (Northern) Vietnamese**

See [this StackExchange answer](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/13182/how-was-the-j-initial-in-middle-chinese-borrowed-into-vietnamese/23195) about certain Middle Chinese lexemes in /j/ (preserved in modern Mandarin and Cantonese), which surface as voiced fricatives /z/ in northern Vietnamese, written as *d* (not to be confused with *đ*) in modern Vietnamese.

**Holtzmann's Law / Verschärfung in Proto-Germanic to Old Norse & Gothic**

E.g. Proto-Germanic [*Frijjō](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/Frijj%C5%8D) resulting in Old Norse *Frigg*, with a /g/ that is retained in modern Scandinavian varieties.

EDIT: [Index Diachronica](https://chridd.nfshost.com/diachronica/) has a list of phonemic changes. For a lot of them I haven't been able to access the original source, but the list is quite long.